# Minimum and maximum response time for the server-side action in Lightning component

Tags: lightning, controller

From the documentation, it is said that server-side actions are asynchronous in Lightning. So, how long will it take for the server-side method to respond back to callback function.

If so, what would be the maximum duration in milliseconds/seconds for the response to come back? What would happen if the transaction that will take a long duration than expected? Will it throw timeout exception?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? There's really not much point in doing specialized error handling as opposed to what you'd do for any other error. Also, the asynchronous nature means that "nothing" would happen for a long-running transaction. It's unclear what answer you seek. Could you [edit] your question with more clarity?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I have updated the question.